# PHP: Convert array to JSON

Tags: php, json

myArray is:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 0
    [2] => 11970.99
    [3] => 2888
    [4] => 0
    [5] => 1500
    [6] => 0
    [7] => 0
    [8] => 0
    [9] => 0
    [10] => 0
    [11] => 0
    [12] => 0
)
```

I want to convert this into JSON, like:

```
[{"name":"Recebimentos","data":[0,11970.99,2888,0,1500,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]}
```

I tried:

```
echo json_encode(array(
            array(name=> 'Recebimentos', data=>$myArray),
        ));
```

But this is returning:

```
[{"name":"Recebimentos","data":{"1":0,"2":11970.99,"3":2888,"4":0,"5":1500,"6":0,"7":0,"8":0,"9":0,"10":0,"11":0,"12":0}}
```

Comment: use `array_values` before encode

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your issue is non-sequencial indexes.
Php array must have indexes `0..array.length-1` to be encoded to JSON array.

You can reset array keys with [array_values](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php%E2%80%8E):

```
echo json_encode(array(
  array(name=> 'Recebimentos', data=>array_values($myArray)),
));
```