# convert multiple array to jSon objects on php

Tags: php, arrays, json

I got an array. I fetched this array from sql table.

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [urunAd] => hamburger [0] => hamburger [Total_Quantity] => 23 [1] => 23 ) [1] => Array ( [urunAd] => cikolatalı pasta [0] => cikolatalı pasta [Total_Quantity] => 11 [1] => 11 ) [2] => Array ( [urunAd] => yogutlu corba [0] => yogutlu corba [Total_Quantity] => 6 [1] => 6 ) )
```

I want to convert php array to jSon objects like this.

```
    doughnutData = [
        {
          value: 200,
          color:"#F7464A",
          highlight: "#FF5A5E",
          label: "Hamburger"
        },
        {
          value: 50,
          color: "#46BFBD",
          highlight: "#5AD3D1",
          label: "Green"
        }
]
```

I tried this for using array_push function push into multi-array.

```
        $sql = "SELECT  urunAd, SUM(adet) AS Total_Quantity
                FROM siparis
                GROUP BY urunNo
                ORDER BY SUM(adet) DESC;";
        $result = $conn->prepare($sql); 
        $result->execute(); 
        $enCokSiparisData = array(
          $s = array(

            ),
          $s2=array(
              "test" => 2
            )
          );

        $number_of_rows = $result->fetchAll();
        foreach ($number_of_rows as $anahtar => $deger) { 
          array_push($s, $deger["Total_Quantity"]);
         }
```

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: Cannot find relation with the array and expected json object.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please use the search function and formulate questions with input, expected output and what you've tried without success. There are [plenty of questions of this kind](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[php]+json+convert+array+is%3Aquestion). Like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22792353/php-convert-array-to-json). It should direct you the right way. Voting for close (duplicate).

Comment: yea there is not relation for array and json object. but i just want to convert.